# Validate form field when page is loaded and while typing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate some form field when the page is refreshed, because they maintain its content and even when it is correct the script does not know it and mark it as incorrect

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#phone').on('input', function() {
          var input=$(this);
          var re =/^[0-9]{9}$/;
          var is_phone=re.test(input.val());
          if(is_phone){input.removeClass("invalid").removeClass("error").addClass("valid");}
          else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
    });
});
```

This code validates the text while typing it, I just want to add a second condition to the on() event but after tried with 'ready' and 'load' it doesn't work.

Comment: You could create a function which does the validation, and bind this function `.on('input'` and call it in your document ready function.

Comment: What is second condition , please share that here?

Comment: @Deep Kakkar Oh sorry, the second condition would be on page refresh (F5). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the logic from the event handler so you can call it from multiple places.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function validateInput ( element ) {

    var input = $(element);
    var re =/^[0-9]{9}$/;
    var is_phone=re.test(input.val());

    if ( is_phone ) {
      input.removeClass("invalid").removeClass("error").addClass("valid"); 
    } else { 
      input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
  }

  // Called on input event
  $('#phone').on('input', function (ev) { validateInput(this); });

  // Called on load
  validateInput( $('#phone') );
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What means the 'ev' as function parameter in the 'on' event call?

Comment: @BraisC it's the `event` object containing information about the click event. Because you're not using it it doesn't actually need to be written there, but it's good practise to show it as a parameter, e.g. `function ( ev ) {}`. Read more here: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/